# ASP .NET with MySQL - use TINYINT with asp:Checkbox

Tags: asp.net, mysql

For my ASP .NET webpage I am using a MySQL database with a TINYINT field to indicate a boolean (0/1) value.

Thanks to stackoverflow I was able to read the field value into a Listview as a asp:Checkbox.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="freight_foundCheckbox" runat="server"
     Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("freight_found")) %>'  />
```

What is challenging me now is how to reverse the transaction in the **InsertItemTemplate** or **EditItemTemplate**.

The listview textbox reads as:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="freight_foundTextBox" runat="server" 
       Text='<%# Bind("freight_found") %>' />
```

How do I bind a asp:Checkbox value back into the database as a integer value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This web site [link text](http://www.aarongoldenthal.com/post/2009/03/15/ASPNET-Databinding-Bind%28%29-Method-Dissected.aspx) was tremendously helpful in resolving this issue.

The key is to capture the value and convert it into a MySQL friendly format before writing to the database.

So for a insert set a **ItemInserting** event with this code:

```
CheckBox freightFound = (CheckBox)ListView2.InsertItem.FindControl("freight_foundCheckbox");
        if (freightFound.Checked == true)
        {               
            //true
            e.Values["freight_found"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //false
            e.Values["freight_found"] = 0;
        }
```

And then for a edit set a **ItemUpdating** event.

```
CheckBox freightFound = (CheckBox)ListView2.EditItem.FindControl("freight_foundCheckbox");

        if (freightFound.Checked == true)
        {
            //true               
            e.NewValues["freight_found"] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //false
            e.NewValues["freight_found"] = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is really old but I just spent a couple of hours trying to get this sorted.

in your UPDATE or INSERT statement you can use this

IF(?='True',1,0)

no need to change a bound checkboxfield to an item template or anything.

I'm not sure if it matters but I changed my parameter type to Boolean and as I now have it working I don't want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late here, but why not just bind it directly to the checkbox instead of a text field? No code behind handling needed that way. See below. MySQL tinyint(1) converts directly to .NET boolean and back when using the MySQL Connector/.NET.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="freight_foundCheckbox" runat="server"
    Checked='<%# Bind("freight_found") %>'  />
```